# Align menu button to right

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to align the button to right side.

```
<div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Logo</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" (click)="collapsed=!collapsed">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
```

[Current alignment of menu bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFw3n.png)

I have already tried using float on button but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `display: flex; width: 100%;` to the parent and put this tag after your `a` tag:

```
<div style="flex-grow: 1"></div>
```

Should be like this:

```
<div class="navbar-header" style="display: flex; width: 100%;">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Logo</a>
  <div style="flex-grow: 1"></div>
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" (click)="collapsed=!collapsed">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: added display flex to navbar-header and div after "a tag" but it is still the same. Should I put "a tag" and button in a separate div?

Comment: try this code @Lambda

Comment: also u can set margin-left: auto on the btn inside flex div

Comment: I made the changes but the output is the same it doesn't move to the right @MahdiZarei

Comment: give `width: 100%` to the parent too. @Lambda